# Group multiplication and taking of inverses are continuous with respect to the topology on $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: geometry, topological-groups, hyperbolic-geometry

I am currently working with the book "Fuchsian groups", by Svetlana Katok and am trying to solve a few of the provided exercises.

I understand $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ can be represented as the quotient group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/(±Id)$ and $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a topological group endowed with a quotient topology. Also it is clear to me how to show that the multiplication and inverses are continuous for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ since it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

However, how would one now show that the group multiplication and inverse are continuous with respect to the topology on $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: This is actually a consequence of a standard property of topological groups. Namely, if $G$ is a topological group and $H$ is a **normal** and **closed** subgroup, then the quotient $G/H$ is also a topological group if endowed with the quotient topology. (This is Exercise 5 at page 146 of Munkres "Topology"). The subgroup $\{I, -I\}$ of $SL(2, \mathbb R)$ is clearly normal and closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a topological group, $N$ a normal (topological) subgroup. We want to show that the quotient group operation $m: G/N \times G/N \to G/N$ is continuous.

We can precompose this map with the product of the canonical projection maps $p: G \times G \to G/N \times G/N$.We can show that this is open and continuous, i.e. a quotient map. We get $mp: G \times G \to G/N$ and now we only need to prove that *this* is continuous:

But this map is equal to the one obtained by composing the group operation map $G\ \times G \to G$ with the projection $G \to G/N$. This map is evidently continuous, so we are done.

Comment: Isn't the point of the question that $PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is not a matrix group but only a quotiont of a matrix group? OP wants to know how to prove that the quotient doesn't destroy continuity.

Comment: @quarague You're right - I've changed my answer to give a more general proof.

Comment: Don't you need that $N$ is closed?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don't think so.

Comment: It probably depends on the definition. According to the convention I follow, a topological group should be Hausdorff, but if you quotient a non-closed subgroup the result is not a Hausdorff space. If you do not require the Hausdorff condition then you are probably fine with what you do in this answer.